# Scrape html with js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to get the html of [www.soccerway.com](http://www.soccerway.com). In particular this:

[image]

that have the `label-wrapper` class I also tried with: `select.nav-select` but I can't get any content. What I did is:

1) Created a php filed called `grabber.php`, this file have this code:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']); ?>
```

2) Created a `index.html` file with this content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="response"></div>

</body>

<script>
    $(function(){
        var contentURI= 'http://soccerway.com';    
        $('#response').load('grabber.php?url='+ encodeURIComponent(contentURI) + ' #label-wrapper');
    });
    var LI = document.querySelectorAll(".list li");
    var result = {};

    for(var i=0; i<LI.length; i++){
        var el = LI[i];
        var elData = el.dataset.value;
        if(elData) result[el.innerHTML] = elData; // Only if element has data-value attr
    }

    console.log( result );
</script>

</html>
```

in the div there is no content grabbed, I tested my js code for get all the link and working but I've inserted the html page [manually](http://jsbin.com/fagezu/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output).

Comment: Your code is potentially very dangerous. `grabber.php?url=/a/path/on/your/server/to/something/very/secret` will not be fun.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Re-read the question. They're proxying the request through the server, avoiding same-origin issues.

Comment: @ceejayoz well spotted. My mistake

Comment: @ceejayoz I only need to get html data and parsing it, I don't need to send data.

Comment: @Dillinger **That doesn't matter.** It's still dangerous. A visitor to your site can access sensitive files (possibly including stuff like database passwords) from your server.

Comment: @ceejayoz uhm it's not a site web script, it's just a cron job system.

Comment: @Dillinger How is your cron job running JavaScript code? Having the `grabber.php` you've shown on a publicly accessible server is **extremely dangerous**.

Comment: @ceejayoz not exactly js directly. I've a php file that run a js file that execute the scrape system, that's it. And I only have the access to this application, no one.

Comment: I wonder use of `cUrl` can be helpful here?

Comment: @techie_28 uhm I generally use `curl` with Rest API. I don't think that could be help

Comment: @Dillinger There's no reason this couldn't be done with cURL and some http://php.net/preg_match or http://php.net/dom.

Comment: @ceejayoz really? I'm running out of ideas apparently

Comment: @ceejayoz would that open vulnerabilities if done by `cUrl`?you think?

Comment: @techie_28 I believe cURL would protect you from the vulnerabilities a simple `file_get_contents` causes.

Comment: PHP code is just `file_get_contents`.I think replacing that with `cUrl` call in someway could be suitable?.. @ceejayoz @Dillinger

Comment: @techie_28 I just want things work, until now still does not go, I'm probably I'm wrong the selector. Then after I think about the security and to optimize everything.

Comment: the link has a long dropdown..you want to get the links?Or the content of each page?

Comment: I have a way to extract the `data-value` & link texts i.e Austria,Australia etc if your PHP code(`file_get_contents`) is returning the HTML correctly?
Please use the base URL in your call & drop `#label-wrapper` & also do a `print_r(file_get_contents($_GET['url']);)` to make sure you are getting HTML there.I will post my solution afterwards @Dillinger

Comment: @techie_28 could you please post an answer solution for this?

Comment: Please paste the output of `print_r(file_get_contents($_GET['url']);)` in http://pastebin.com/.. I will need to see that first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple issues here.

```
var contentURI= 'http:/soccerway.com #label-wrapper';
```

You're missing the second slash in `http://`, and you're passing a URL with a space and an ID to `file_get_contents`. You'll want this instead:

```
var contentURI = 'http://soccerway.com/';
```

and then you'll need to parse out the item you're interested in from the resulting HTML.

The `#label-wrapper` needs to be in the jQuery `load()` call, not the `file_get_contents`, and the contentURI variable needs to be properly escaped with `encodeURIComponent`:

```
$('#response').load('grabber.php?url='+ encodeURIComponent(contentURI) + ' #label-wrapper');
```

Your code also contains a **massive** vulnerability that's potentially very dangerous, as it allows anyone to access `grabber.php` with a `url` value that's a file location on your server. This could compromise your database password or other sensitive data on the server.

Comment: @Dillinger I've updated, but **you** need to start debugging. Your browser's console is likely full of error messages that'd hint at the issues. You've posted awful code that couldn't possibly work for a variety of reasons - you need to understand what it's doing.

Comment: In the `network` tab I see only : `object {}` that is the result of: `console.log( result );` I update the question with the update code. +1 for the help.

Comment: @Dillinger That's probably because, as far as I can tell, the website doesn't have any element with an ID of `label-wrapper` in its HTML.

Comment: So I can't achieve my goal

Comment: @Dillinger Not with `#label-wrapper`. Find the **right** jQuery selector to apply to the content. Was `#label-wrapper` a random guess? Why'd you pick it?

Comment: I just clicked inspect element and the `<select>` have this class: `#label-wrapper` but I just noticed that is a class not an id.